# Category is not placed at the correct section

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem while printing categories and sections (for a forum). So I have 2 tables : forum_section and forum_category -> the cat_id column from forum_section is linked with the `section` column from forum_category. Here's my query:

```
$forum = $con->query("SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM `forum_section` a
    INNER JOIN `forum_category` b ON a.`cat_id` = b.`section` GROUP BY a.`cat_name` ORDER BY a.`cat_id`");
```

And that's how I'm trying to print them:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($forum)) {
        echo '<div id="section">
              <div class="section-head"><h3 class="yellow_text">'.$row->cat_name.'</h3></div>
                '.printCategories($row->cat_id).'
            </div>';
    }
}
```

That's my printCategories function:

```
function printCategories($id) {
    global $con;

    $categories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `forum_category` WHERE `section`='$id'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($categories)) {
        echo '<div class="cat">
                <div class="cat-title">
                  <img src="styles/default/images/icons/'.$row->icon.'.png" alt="Icon">
                  <span>'.$row->name.'</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cat-topics">
                    asd
                </div>
                <div class="cat-posts">
                    asd
                </div>
                <div class="cat-lasttopic">
                    last topic name goes here
                </div>
              </div>';
    }
}
```

So it does print them but not in the right place as you can see in this picture: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printCategories` needs to `return` the result, not `echo` it, so that the concatenation in the caller will put it into the `DIV` that it's `echo`ing. Your code is echoing before it returns anything, so it gets printed before the caller concatenates the result and prints its `DIV`.

```
function printCategories($id) {
    global $con;

    $categories = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `forum_category` WHERE `section`='$id'");
    $result = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($categories)) {
        $result += '<div class="cat">
                <div class="cat-title">
                  <img src="styles/default/images/icons/'.$row->icon.'.png" alt="Icon">
                  <span>'.$row->name.'</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cat-topics">
                    asd
                </div>
                <div class="cat-posts">
                    asd
                </div>
                <div class="cat-lasttopic">
                    last topic name goes here
                </div>
              </div>';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Yep it seems that was the problem. Thanks for your time.